# Cross thread BeginInvoke blocking under heavy CPU load

Tags: .net, winforms, multithreading

I have a Windows Form User Control that contains a 3rd party image display control which is updated from a separate thread using a BeginInvoke delegate call.

Under heavy CPU load the UI locks up. When I attach a debugger it is always on the same line of code where it is updating the 3rd party image control.

```
    public ICogImage DisplayImage
    {
        get { return this.ResultImageCogDisplay.Image; }
        set 
        {
           this.BeginInvoke((ThreadStart)delegate
            {
                this.ResultImageCogDisplay.Image = value;
            });

        }
    }
```

If I comment out the implementation of the setter, then the problem goes away.

**Can anyone explain why this is happening?**

Some more info:

- The image update events are generated periodically (~200ms) from a frame grabber card. The events are raised on separate threads.
- I believe that the 3rd party image control uses ActiveX, it is part of an vision processing framework from Cognex.
- The images are approx. 900x800 8 bit grayscale
- There are 4 of these controls on the form, each feeding from different threads with different images.
- I've tried it with and without the IsInvokeRequired() check, it doesn't seem to make any difference.

**Are there any limits on the number of messages on the PostMessage queue, which I am hitting under high CPU load?**

Answer (score 4):

`BeginInvoke` queues an action to be performed on a UI thread.  If you queue enough things to do that the UI can't keep up with them, you'll overwhelm the UI thread and it will appear hung.  Try throttling the event back to maybe once a second to see if that helps.

Comment: Is it possible to find the number of messages on this queue, just as a way of proving its the cause? Would the amount of image data I'm posting on the queue be a factor (I could scale down the images). Unfortunately the app must display the images as its used for QA of a manufacturing process.

Comment: The amount of data, the speed at which the data can be processed, etc. Is a factor to whether the UI thread can keep up.  I don't think there's a way to.prove it, but throttling back the amount if data and it relieves the problem will tell you a lot.

Comment: Try posting a `Console.WriteLine` to the UI thread that captures the `DateTime.Now` when you posted the code and subtracts it from the `DateTime.Now` that the code actually executed. Then you can determine the approximate lag that the UI thread is experiencing. If you need it to be more accurate then try using `StopWatch` instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed a limit on Windows Message Queue entries, (at least, there is on 32-bit systems), of 10,000 entries.  Long before that happens,  siezing up the GUI is quite easy to do by posting messages faster than the GUI can process them - I have done this often:((

Usually, my designs use a pool of objects for inter-thread comms, so I get round this issue because the producer thread gets blocked on the pool queue if the GUI is not returning 'used' objects fast enough, so providing overall flow-control. Of course, while stopping GUI lockups, this does not help much if you have a frame-rate requirement that cannot be met :(

Comment: I changed from a BeginInvoke to an Invoke as I though that it would block the calling method until the update was complete (sync) - however it didn't make any different. Saying that, there DisplayImage property above is updated from event handlers about 3-4 levels deep, some of which use Delegate.BeginInvoke() which (AFAIK) uses a thread pool similar to what you use - but you would have a lot more control over the pool size.

Comment: I have digital I/O handshaking with the framegrabber which I can use to skip/reject the next product being inspected, so if I can slow down the image updates to an acceptable rate (which won't hang the UI) then I might have a solution. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Changing from BeginInvoke to Invoke likely doesn't decrease the workload; but probably does mean that the queue isn't being overloaded.  Invoke simply blocks the current thread and lets the UI invoke the action.  If you're still having problems with hanging, the workload of setting DisplayImage and showing the image likely can't be done faster than 4-5 times a second.  Not many normal controls are able to get much of a "frame rate" they're expected to show a static image that get's set once.